# Download S3 and Add to App Directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk Node app that I'm trying to setup. I'm trying to load an environment file from S3 into `/var/app/ondeck/src/` so the file is available when the Node app is started. I've tried as many things as I can think of but the production.env file never shows up. If I change the location to something like `/home/ec2-user` the file appears so I know that I have the file part correct. What am I missing?

```
files:
  "/var/app/ondeck/src/production.env":
    mode: "000777"
    user: nodejs
    group: nodejs
    source: https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/file.env

Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Access:
          type: S3
          roleName: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
          buckets: bucket-name
```

========

A last resort idea was to run a container_command that would just copy the file from `/home/ec2-user` into `/var/app/current/src/` or `/var/app/ondeck/src/` but that didn't seem to work either. I prefer to get the top example to work if at all possible.

```
container_commands:
  command: "/bin/cp /home/ec2-user/production.env /var/app/ondeck/production.env"
```

Comment: why are you using the "ondeck" folder rather than the "current" one? the ondeck probably gets deleted alongside your file. try to ssh the box and see for yourself if that folder even exist after deployment

Comment: Ondeck is created while the app is deploying. If all goes well it deletes current and renames ondeck to current if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I've tried loading the file into current as well but no success.

Answer (score 9):

Your latter option seems to be working for me with some modifications. Note the following:

- I use `mv` instead of `cp`
- in my case I have an owner and group of `webapp` instead of `nodejs`, but probably that's just because of me using Beanstalk for PHP rather than Node
- I have a name for my container command
- I'm using a relative path for the container command's destination file
- I haven't tested with authentication since my particular use case involves a file that is public

It'd be something like:

```
files:
  "/home/ec2-user/production.env":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: nodejs
    group: nodejs
    source: https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/file.env

container_commands:
  01_mv_to_app_dir:
    command: "mv /home/ec2-user/production.env ./production.env"
```