# AWS Beanstalk - On Deploy, Copy file with env variables from S3 bucket?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm attempting to copy a file from an S3 bucket to an NodeJS app on Beanstalk when I deploy a new version.

What I've done so far:

1. Created a S3 bucket and uploaded the files.
2. Created IAM Policy that allows the Beanstalk instance (aws-beanstalk-ec2-role) to read the bucket files.
3. Set Bucket policy to allow aws-beanstalk-ec2-role to access the files.
4. Created a config file in my app at .ebextensions/app.config with this:

> ```
>   Resources:
>     AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
>         Metadata:
>             AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
>                 S3Auth:
>                     type: "s3"
>                     buckets: ["bucket-name"]
>                     roleName: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
>
>   files:
>     "/tmp/deployment/application/file_needed.json" :
>       mode: "000644"
>       owner: root
>       group: root
>       authentication: "S3Auth"
>       source: https://[bucket-name].s3.[region].amazonaws.com/origin_file.json
> ```

The app deploys with no errors, but the file, file_needed.json, does not get copied?

Update: After trying a different folder destination (/tmp), I've found that files are copied.
What I know is that Beanstalk first extracts the files to /tmp/deployment/application/, and then moves them to /var/app/current.
How can I get the files to copy to the root directory of the app?

Comment: Have you checked any logs on the instance in /var/log folder or though the EB console? Maybe there is some permission deny or some other message which could be useful.

Comment: @Marcin yes checked the logs, no errors, but also no indication that it's trying to get the file. Is there some way I can do a "console.log" in app.config to have something appear in the logs?

Comment: You can create second file in `files` section. Just some dummy `/tmp/dummy.txt` to check if the `app.config` is even executed.

Comment: @Marcin I added a file that does not exist, and it does show an error (Failed to retrieve (fake_file) HTTP Error 403 ). So it is reading the config file.

Comment: @Marcin I managed to copy to /tmp as a test. So seems to be an issue of how to get the file to the right folder (app root).

Comment: Maybe copy it to tmp if its working first. and then using other config file in ebextansions copy it to final destination. maybe the `/tmp/deployment/application/` does not exist when the app.config runs? Or the `/tmp/deployment/application/` is overwritten by EB itself.

Comment: Hi JBS, I'm having this same issue, please were you able to fix it, if so how?

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be a case-sensitivity issue. In AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication the type is set to "s3" instead of "S3".

Also try removing “region” from the bucket URL:

```
source: https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/origin_file.json
```

Comment: Worth a shot but no change

Comment: Are you able to find the logs? Try looking in places like /var/log/eb-tools.log

Comment: nothing showing in the logs, but when I try add a fake file it does report a 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [Download S3 and Add to App Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918629/download-s3-and-add-to-app-directory)

I used the default bucket created by EB and added a new role with permissions to  read from S3

Also to copy the files you should use container_commands
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands

Whatever files you want to copy need to be added to the staging folder, this is mentioned in the above link

this is what I used to copy the file to my deployed code

```
    command: "mv /home/ec2-user/.env.production /var/app/staging/.env.production"
```

Also if you want your file to readable change the owner and group to `webapp`

this command shows you all available users `less /etc/passwd`

To find your apps user group you can also just check the permission of the files in `app/current`